# Create dynamic names in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    PivotGridField field + i = new PivotGridField();
}
```

Of course, this code will not work, but how to make it work this way, as I need to create unknown number of fields.

Thanks!

Comment: I want to create field for each row in datatable, and datatable doesn't have fixed number of rows. And I need to have different names for them.

Comment: won't autogenerate columns help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create fields (or, as in this case, variables) on the fly. What you *can* do is have an array / list / similar:

```
PivotGridField[] fields = new PivotGridField[DT1.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    fields[i] = new PivotGridField();
}
```

Now whenever you want "field n", use `fields[n]`

Comment: Or use Key,Vaule dictionary array such a way that Key is one of the Database column value

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in different ways. First you can use an array like Marc suggested. Alternative is to use dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,PivotGridField> fields = new Dictionary<string, PivotGridField>();
for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    fields["field"+i] = new PivotGridField();
}

fields["field1"] = ...
```

Third method is to use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DYNAMIC.EXPANDOOBJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

```
dynamic fields = new ExpandoObject();
for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ((IDictionary<String, Object>) fields).Add("field" + i, new PivotGridField());
}
```

You can then access your fields as if they were real member fields:

```
fields.field1 = ...
fields.field2 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in C# you can't generate variables' name dynamically.

But you can set various field properties' value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    PivotGridField field = new PivotGridField();
    field.Name = "Name " + i;
    grid.Fields.Add(field);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could instead create a list of type PivotGridField and add to list on each iteration. If one of the properties of PivotGridField is something like "name", you can set it to be "field" + i.

Answer (score 0):

You can create fields/properties on the fly in C#, but only for a specific sort of object. Using an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject.aspx), you can do this:

```
    ExpandoObject expando = new ExpandoObject();
    IDictionary<string, object> expandoAsDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    expando.Add("MyTotallyNewProperty", "MyTotallyNewPropertyValue");
    Console.WriteLine(expando.MyTotallyNewProperty); //this will print "MyTotallyNewPropertyValue"
```

You can customize the nature of your dynamic object by inheriting from `DynamicObject`. read up on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.aspx).

That said, in your case, you should instead use the other suggestions. Dynamic objects should only be used as required, and in your case, a dynamic data structure would do the trick quite nicely. Remember that just because the word 'field' appears in the specification, doesn't mean you need to use the C# concept of a field to implement it.

NOTE: `DynamicObject` only exists in .NET 4.0 or higher. There are no convenient ways of doing this in previous versions.